# Jmeter assertion css, как правильно сделать ассершн по css

Tags: css, jmeter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался,
идет запрос на страницу, на которой есть нужный элемент [image: html]

с помощью какого ассершена сделать, я пытался с помощью xPath assertion, но что-то не выходит, 
в жиметре сначала тянется экстрактором нужный кусок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом с помощью xPath assertion пытался чекнуть

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно проверить присутствие [HTML тэга `<a>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp), значение [аттрибута `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) которого `permission btn btn-success on` с помощью [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), соответствующий селектор будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
//a[@class='permission btn btn-success on']
```

Полная конфигурация [XPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ответ не в формате [XHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp) вам придется поставить галку 'Use Tidy (tolerant parser)`

Подробная информация по JMeter Assertions: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/)

Comment: сделал, так как у Вас, у меня все равно не проходит ассершн, и когда хочу проверить через xpath tester не находит этот элемент http://prntscr.com/rpfd35

Comment: Может быть это связанно с экстрактором, хотя вроде должно все норм работать http://prntscr.com/rpg6gb он тащит всю эту таблицу до конца страницы http://prntscr.com/rpg738 , создается переменная и я ее вставляю в xpath assertion http://prntscr.com/rpg7wo

Comment: `XPath Tester` нужно выполнять на том сэмплере, который возвращает вашу ссылку, а не на Debug Sampler. Я не знаю значения вашей переменной `userPermission`, но это точно не XML/HTML навряд ли XPath Assertion сработает на ней. Может вам будет проще вытащить значение с помощью ]Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) и затем проверить что оно не равно Default Value обычным [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)?

Comment: Спасибо Вам  большое, в такой связке все сделал, все работает как нужно)